# run software even without windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, assembly

is there any way to make a software , so if the user reinstall windows or format disk drive , the software will run without installing automatically .

I do not mean a software that do not require installation .

think a user install this software , this software automatically run . one day user format hard disk and install a new windows . that software run automatically without installing .

Comment: Can you be more specific I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: You mean software that is automatically present when the user re-installs windows from scratch? I think therefore you will have to work at microsoft.

Comment: You could slipstream it into the Windows install much like some OEM's do.

Comment: you could check out: http://www.nccgroup.com/Libraries/Document_Downloads/02_07_Firmware_Rootkits_The_Threat_to_the_Enterprise_Black_Hat_Washington_2007_sflb.sflb.ashx

Comment: Of course, real hackers write their malware without resorting to Q&A sites.

Comment: @David: I'm not scared of malware authors who've only just thought of this. It puts them about 25 years behind the curve.

Comment: @ata another option you can consider is writing your own operating system and have your software integral part of it. If Google did that, you can to! ;)

Comment: @Shadow Google didn't do that. They just customised Linux.

Comment: @David oh my.. and I started to respect Google! Well my point is still the same.... without your own customized OS such thing is not really possible. :)

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically yes, but the question to ask is, "where is the executable for this program stored?"

Normally programs are stored on the hard disk, so if the user formats it, the program is gone[*]. So the question is, "where else can code be stored?"

The answer is that, in theory, you can replace the machine's [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS). This is a very abnormal thing to do, though, it requires all the admin privileges in the world, and the BIOS program can't be very big.

It also can't be written in C# or C++ in the usual Windows-y ways. Firstly the BIOS runs before Windows is running, that's the point. Secondly removing the OS removes the libraries that Windows programs rely on, so if the system drive has been formatted and Windows *not* re-installed, there's no way to launch Windows and hence no way to start your Windows program.

[*] Boot sector viruses are way out of fashion.

Comment: Boot sector viruses are not only out of fashion, but also easily formatted away with the rest of the HD's contents if you know what you're doing. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: if. We just don't know what kind of format the questioner is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

If the user formats his hard drive and powers off his computer, there is no software left on the system that could be run.

No, this cannot be done (unless you re-flash the BIOS).

Answer (score 0):

You can make it portable. Thus you can copy executable on non-system partition and it will still work.

But I dont think there is any way to register this application in fresh windows instalation without modifying the instalation process itself. But registration for autorun is easy and can be done when user first runs application manualy.